# Woocommerce cart is spliting items that are over 199

Tags: woocommerce

### I'm testing my new shop in woocommerce, and I have stuck in problem that when I add over 199 items to cart, its automaticlly splting them to less quantity, for example i have added 400 pens to cart, and it shows:
-199
-100
-100

Screenshot of that problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyIDQ.jpg

Thanks in advance for help.
Greetings

I tried to find fixed of this problem in stackoverflow searach, i was trying to fix it by myself. I tried look for it in google, I even ask AI to solve this, but nothing helped.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really that kind of support forum but:
Make sure you have added that quantity in your pproduct. so if you add 999
Make sure you either have 999 in the stock or unlimited.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes I have added the stock of over 999, but it doesn't solve the problem, I have tried add a code


'code'
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'bbloomer_override_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );

function bbloomer_override_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ) {
    if ( $cart_item['quantity'] >= 199 ) {
        $product_quantity = sprintf( '<div class="quantity">%s</div>', $cart_item['quantity'] );
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}